# The archive manager is saying that there is an error loading the archive

Tags: wine, itunes

I am trying to install iTunes to install my iPad's software. When I load the archive, it says there is an error loading the archive. I am using [this](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-and-use-itunes-on-ubuntu/) link to install iTunes. How to fix it?

Comment: It does not let me create a tag because of reputation so I had to put the tag "archive". So ignore the tag I put. It does not relate to the question.

Comment: @ToDo, can you help me?